# Azure function erroring on manual run but works fine on schedule

Tags: azure-functions

I have a daily scheduled function that is running happily and triggering each day and completing without error.

If I try to run that function manually it errors with an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

It's a simple function that reads from an Azure SQL table and puts a few small json items onto a storage queue

If I set the SQL connection string and Storage connection string locally to match the deployed version and run through VS2017 it also runs without error

Comment: I have added various Log.LogInformation statements to my function including one at the very top that never gets called so the error is upstream from my function

Comment: Problem may arise from how you manually run the function, could you elaborate?

Comment: Can you please provide some code of your function. That would make analysis easier.